# jQuery: click list items, in sequence, at a certain interval

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I am working on a script that should simulate clicks on *each* item of a list (of anchors), with an interval between clicks.

Once the click trigger reaches the last item, it should star all over from the first. For this purpose, I have written:

```js
var animationInterval = 5000;

var autoAdvance = setInterval(function() {
  $('.slider-nav a').each(function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
  });
}, animationInterval);

autoAdvance();

$('.slider-nav a').on(click, function() {
  $('.slider-nav a').closest('li').removeClass("active");
  $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.slider-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider-nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.slider-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.slider-nav li.active a {
  background: #c00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav-container">
  <ul class="slider-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For a reason i cannot understand the script does not work, giving the error: `autoAdvance is not a function`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove `autoAdvance()` statement. Error is correct as `autoAdvance` refers to `intervalID` returned by `setInterval`

Comment: I did. And there is no execution of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var animationInterval = 5000;

var autoAdvance = function() {

setInterval(function() {

 if ($('.slider-nav li.active').index() + 1 != $('.slider-nav li').length) {
  $('.slider-nav li.active').next().find('a').trigger('click');
 } else {
  $('.slider-nav li:first').find('a').trigger('click');
 }
 
}, animationInterval)

};

autoAdvance();

$('.slider-nav a').on("click", function() {
  $('.slider-nav a').closest('li').removeClass("active");
  $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.slider-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider-nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.slider-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.slider-nav li.active a {
  background: #c00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav-container">
  <ul class="slider-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing on a couple of points:

- You can execute setInterval directly.
- You need to trigger click on just one element. Calculate it using some variable.
- `$('.slider-nav a').on(click` `click` needs to be in quotes

```js
var animationInterval = 1000;
var index = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  $('.slider-nav li:eq('+index+') a').trigger('click');
  index++;
  if(index == $('.slider-nav li').length){
    index = 0;
  }
}, animationInterval);

$('.slider-nav a').on("click", function() {
  $('.slider-nav a').closest('li').removeClass("active");
  $(this).closest('li').addClass("active");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.nav-container {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.slider-nav {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider-nav li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.slider-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 3px;
  background: #222;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.slider-nav li.active a {
  background: #c00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="nav-container">
  <ul class="slider-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```